# Check if JTable contains column with identifier

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Simple question. Is there any way to check if a `JTable` contains a column before calling `getColumn(Object identifier)` ?

```
JTable table = ...;
table.getColumn("header");
```

`getColumn()` throws a `IllegalArgumentException` if the header doesn't exist. So, is catching that exception the only way to check for the column? Looking for a `hasColumn()` or `doesColumnExist()` or `isColumnValid()` but, alas, nothing.

Comment: You could use the `TableColumnModel` directly

Comment: @MadProgrammer, the `TableColumnModel` cannot retrieve columns based on `Object identifier`. =/

Comment: Yep, exactly as @MadProgrammer says, you can use the methods to enumerate through the Columns checking if one exists. You can get the columns by index, and then easily compare the names. Just a little imagination and you should solve it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I think I'd rather just catch the exception as opposed to iterating through every column every time lol =/

Comment: Nah, for my money, I'd go with @MadProgrammer's answer. The cost of the code is minimal. 1+.

Comment: Essentially, this is what the `TableColumnModel` is doing, except, instead of returning `null` when it can't find a column, it throws an exception. You should avoid using exceptions as logic controllers as there might be multiple reasons why the exception is thrown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply iterate over the `TableColumnModel`'s available columns and see if it contains the available column, for example...

```
JTable table = ...;
Object identifier = ...;
TableColumnModel model = table.getColumnModel();
boolean found = false;
for (int index = 0; index < model.getColumnCount(); index++) {
    if (model.getColumn(index).getIdentifier().equals(identifier)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }            
}
```

For example...And yes, I would write this into a helper method/class so you can reuse it.

You should avoid using exceptions as logic controllers, as there might a number of reasons an exception might be raised

Comment: column can be removed from JTables view, talking only about events in the JTables view